# Object mapped material orientation based rotation and area based offset

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm running into two main issues in Blender 4.0.2 with a material that is using box projection for it's textures.

As for the first issue, I would like to rotate the textures on this material by 45 degrees, though when this is done in the mapping node, it rotates it only for the singular axis, warping the image on the other two axis.
[image]

What would be the best way to fix this problem I'm running into to have it so that it rotates it 45 degrees only along the one axis for every surface? I've tried using both the texture coordinates' outputs like normal and UV, as well as the geometry output's sockets to no luck.

As for the second issue, I am trying to achieve a way so that I can offset a texture based on how many tiles can fit into the available surface that it is applied to, so if a tile for example is 60 cm and a wall you apply this material to is 90 cm, I would like it to be able to offset the textures so that it will be split down the middle and applies two tiles of 45 cm each, though if a wall would be 120 cm it would place two whole tiles next to eachother. Though this should also follow the same logic as the rotation issue since it should offset along the way it is facing.

For additional context I have a material that has a 3x3 grid of these 60x60 cm tiles, meaning that one texture would be 180x180 cm. I assume something along the lines of dividing it by 3 would be one of the steps required?

This would be the desired effect though it is done manually per individual wall size.
[image]

I feel like these two issues might be linked to eachother, and hope that the info I have provided is helpful. If need be I could also attach the blender file.

Comment: Hello, for the first issue I guess you need to use the UV output or rotate the texture itself in an image editor like Gimp/Krita/Photoshop

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, sadly using the UV output would mean losing the scale being based on physical size, no? Since the way I have it set up now with both object texture coordinates and box projection it makes it be based on scale, though makes the rotation not possible like how I want it. Is there a possible middleground?

Comment: You might look at triplanar mapping nodes I shared at https://blenderartists.org/t/triplanar-node-blender-2-81/1206622/8 .  This is intended for use with three different textures, but you could use a single texture with 3 different mappings instead.